# EhCache3 + Spring Boot 2 without XML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ehcache-3

I'm stuck finding solution how to implement EhCache3 with Spring Boot 2. The problem is that in version 3 they changed package to org.ehcache and examples of xml-less configuration I found are for 2 version where you declare net.sf.ehcache.config. and I want to work with 3rd version.

```
 package com.jcg.example.ehcache_no_xml.config;

import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class EhCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheCacheManager testEhCacheManager() {
        // testEhCache Configuration - create configuration of cache that previous required XML
        CacheConfiguration testEhCacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration()
            .eternal(false)                     // if true, timeouts are ignored
            .timeToIdleSeconds(3)               // time since last accessed before item is marked for removal
            .timeToLiveSeconds(5)               // time since inserted before item is marked for removal
            .maxEntriesLocalHeap(10)            // total items that can be stored in cache
            .memoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU")   // eviction policy for when items exceed cache. LRU = Least Recently Used
            .name("testCache");

        Cache testCache = new Cache(testEhCacheConfig);

        cacheManager().getObject().addCache(testCache);
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManager().getObject());
    }
}
```

Is there any solution ho to create ehCache configuration propramaticaly with spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I will post my answer as I've resolved this problem along ago.
I'm using Spring Boot and next dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
  <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My cache config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager() {
        return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager());
    }

    @Bean(value = "cacheManager")
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();
        List<String> cacheNames = Arrays.asList("myCacheName");
        cacheNames.forEach(cn -> cacheManager.createCache(cn, config()));
        return cacheManager;
    }

    private MutableConfiguration<SimpleKey, SiteIdSet> config() {
        return new MutableConfiguration<SimpleKey, SiteIdSet>()
                .setTypes(SimpleKey.class, ClassWhichShouldBeCached.class)
                .setStoreByValue(false);
    }

}
```

During the start a have a method which retrieves some values and then cache them:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@DependsOn("cacheManager")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    ommited ...

    @Override
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "myCacheName")
    public Set<Integer> getSmth() {
        return callDb();
    }

    @Override
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "myCacheName")
    public Set<Integer> getSmth() {
        return callDb();
    }
}
```

I won't describe what this methods do, but they work with defined cache and populate and renew it when need.